# easiest way to configure 3 roles in spring security 4 / JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I already have the spring security working for user and admin. Access is granted only for authenticated users, with some pages allowed only for admin. But that's nearly the default configuration.

Now I want to add a third role (let's name it crip) in spring security. The 3 roles are like russian nesting dolls : user has access to 3 pages, crip has access to theses 3 pages + 2 others and the admin is a super user so he has access to everything.

On the hibernate/ JPA side, is it better to use a set of roles for a user with onetomany relation between autorities and user table or just one Role ? This role would be defined hierarchical : Admin > crip > user.

If the definition of roles is the best way to do this, on the spring security side, how do I configure the role inclusion : Admin > crip > user?

I've found @manytoone and @manytomany relationship between users and roles, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-hierarchical-roles)?

Comment: @M.Deinum. I've read some docs and tutorial on spring security. I've already done the default /initial configuration with admin and user role. But it was just forbiding some pages from other users than admin. So there was not much configurations to do. Now with the third role it seems more complicated and I've found less documentation (seems normal btw).

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood, you already have basic configuration and got it working.

so just add this to intercept url list

if you want to allow access for roles - Admin, crisp or user

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pagesForCrispAndAdminAndUser**" access="hasAnyAuthority('Admin', 'crisp', 'user')" />
```

Allow only Admin

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pagesForAdmin**" access="hasAuthority('Admin')" />
```

Allow Admin and user

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pagesForAdminAndUser**" access="hasAnyAuthority('Admin', 'user')" />
```

documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html)